# Rails: Migrate doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have  a little problem with my db schema.
I have create a migration named `messages` but it was no good so I deleted them for replace by the good `messages` migration.
But in my schema I have the last `messages` migration yet.

How it's possible?

**rails db:migrate:status:**

```
 up 20160924085640  Create conversations
 up 20160924090519  Create messages
```

schema.rb:

```
create_table "conversations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "sender_id"
  t.integer "recipient_id"
end

create_table "messages", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.string   "subject"
  t.string   "body"
  t.integer  "recipient_id"
  t.integer  "sender_id"

end
```

**migration:**

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.references :conversation, index: true
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.boolean :read, :default => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**routes**

```
 resources :conversations do
  resources :messages
 end
```

When I try to access to /conversations

I have this error:  `uninitialized constant ConversationsController`

Comment: when you try to access `/conversations `, It means it searches for the `index` method of `ConversationsController.rb`. Your `ConversationsController.rb` is missing. This is not problem of migrations.

Comment: yeah it s a other prob^^ but why i havent the same migration in my shema and in migration file ?

Comment: class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
   i have create a conversations controller but it's doesn't  working .. I have my methode etc but impossible acess to "conversations" ...

Answer (score 0):

First You should read about rails routes and their correspond action in controller

For Every Route
You should have one controller
one action in controller for desired route
and one view(erb) filw in views

Like for your query
In controller
Create index action
than in views => conversations  => index.html.erb

Comment: yeah i know that ^^ i have create all that my conversationscontroller is okay . can you loook my create methode ?                                                 **def create
    if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],params[:recipient_id])
   .present?
    conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id],
     params[:recipient_id]).first
   else
    conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
    end **

Comment: error when i want create conversation **undefined method `between?' for #<Class:0x007fa40a99b140>**

Comment: are you created between method in Conversation model

Comment: yeah. scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
 where(“(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?)”, sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
 end

Comment: SyntaxError in ConversationsController#index i don't find my syntaxe errro

Comment: change name "between" ... n create method rather than scope
scope should be only for one line query